# Draw a NSString in a PDF (watermark)

Tags: swift, image, pdf, nsstring, draw

This question I've been posted many times but I still cannot find the correct answer. My aim is to load a PDF (questionnaire pages scanned), mark each page with the page number and save each in separate JPEG files for later use. All works fine except that the NSString is not drawn. I worked perfectly when I created a NSGraphicsContext from a bitmap representation but the image resolution was too low. So, I conclude it is a PDF issue but could not figure out what it is.

```
    let PDFAsData = try Data(contentsOf: pathname)
    let dataInPDF = NSPDFImageRep(data: PDFAsData)!
    let numberOfPages = dataInPDF.pageCount

    for i in 0..<numberOfPages {
        let pdfPage=pdfDocument.page(at: i+1)!
        let mediaBoxRect = pdfPage.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        let scale:CGFloat = 200.0/72.0
        let width = Int(mediaBoxRect.width * scale)
        let height = Int(mediaBoxRect.height * scale)
        let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)!
        context.interpolationQuality = .high
        context.scaleBy(x: scale, y: scale)
        context.drawPDFPage(pdfPage)
        context.saveGState()
        do {
             let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default().mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
             paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.left
             let textFontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: NSFont(name: "Arial Bold", size: 10.0)!,
             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.black,
             NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]
             let text = "\(fileNameNSString), page: \(i+1)" as NSString
             text.draw(at: CGPoint(x:10, y:10), withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
         }
         context.flush()
         context.restoreGState()
         let image=context.makeImage()!  // Creates and returns a CGImage to be saved as JPEG
    }
```

Comment: I found part of the solution using CATextLayer but I cannot yet change the position of the string on the page...

let textLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.string = "\(fileNameNSString), page: \(i+1)"
textLayer.font = "Arial Bold" as CFTypeRef?
textLayer.fontSize = 10.0
textLayer.foregroundColor = CGColor.black
textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentLeft
textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 50)
textLayer.draw(in: context)
let image=context.makeImage()!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PDFKit in your project? If yes, download Apple's sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/custom_graphics).
and replace line:

```
let string: NSString = "U s e r   3 1 4 1 5 9"
```

with this line:

```
let string: NSString = NSString(format: "Page %@", "\(self.pageRef?.pageNumber ?? 0)")
```